# How to interpret output from nparcomp in R

Tags: r, interpretation

I have skewed data requiring non-parametric tests. Following Kruskal Wallis tests, I want to carry out post-hoc analysis. I have chosen
`nparcomp` within R because of recommendations here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-January/300100.html

As an example, using the ChickWeight dataset within R, the following code:

```
> npar <- nparcomp(weight~Diet, data=ChickWeight, type="Tukey")
> summary(npar)
```

Gives the following output:

```
#------------Nonparametric Multiple Comparisons for relative contrast effects---------# 

- Alternative Hypothesis:  True relative contrast effect p is less or equal than 1/2    
- Estimation Method: Global Pseudo ranks 
- Type of Contrast : Tukey 
- Confidence Level: 95 % 
- Method = Logit - Transformation 

- Estimation Method: Pairwise rankings 

#---------------------------Interpretation--------------------------------------------# 
p(a,b) > 1/2 : b tends to be larger than a 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------# 

#----Data Info------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
  Sample Size
1      1  220
2      2  120
3      3  120
4      4  118

#----Contrast------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
       1  2  3 4
2 - 1 -1  1  0 0
3 - 1 -1  0  1 0
4 - 1 -1  0  0 1
3 - 2  0 -1  1 0
4 - 2  0 -1  0 1
4 - 3  0  0 -1 1


 #----Analysis-----------------------------------------------------------------------# 
  Comparison Estimator Lower Upper   Statistic      p.Value
1 p( 1 , 2 )     0.575 0.489 0.657  2.24129062 0.1105119928
2 p( 1 , 3 )     0.628 0.540 0.708  3.70156665 0.0010425555
3 p( 1 , 4 )     0.638 0.551 0.717  3.99792977 0.0002112224
4 p( 2 , 3 )     0.560 0.464 0.652  1.59731987 0.3805179622
5 p( 2 , 4 )     0.562 0.465 0.655  1.64558875 0.3512047996
6 p( 3 , 4 )     0.497 0.401 0.592 -0.08324927 0.9999818119

 #----Overall------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
  Quantile      p.Value
1 2.561994 0.0002112224

 #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

I am unsure how to interpret this output, in particular:
1.The contrast section, what do the different values of -1, 0 or 1 mean
2.The analysis section, how should the tabulated values be interpreted.

Am new to stack.exchange so apologies if this would be better placed in the statistics forum

Many thanks for help in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need this answer but here goes:

1. The contrast section is determined by which option you choose in the `type` argument of `nparcomp`. In this case that is Tukey. Tukey contrasts are "translated" to a contrast matrix as you see in your output. In this case all pairwise comparisons are executed and this is what you see in the matrix translating in -1, 1 and 0 to make the comparisons of e.g. group 2 - group 1 (2-1). I hope this answers your question on that matter?
2. The analysis section gives you the following columns: Estimator - which is the estimated value of the specific comparison's relative contrast effect with it's lower & upper boundaries of the 95% confidence interval. The test statistic, is the calculated statistic as described [here](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v64/i09/paper) which then is compared to a critical value to result a p value which is multiplicity corrected with your chosen method.

I do strongly recommend that for questions like these you consult the help `?nparcomp` and just check the package reference manual first since this could have already solved the question before asking it here.